# Change the value of an input field on select

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating this online store with a javascript shopping cart. Some products have options, and an option changes the price of an item. The price of an item used to be in a span, but I thought that a disabled input field looks better. My problem is that my code doesn't change the value of the input field, but it did change it when the price was written in span.

The jQuery:

```
$(".item_lenght").change(function() {
        $('.item_price').html($('option:selected', this).data('price'));
    });
```

And the html:

```
<table style="border:1px solid black; border-radius: 6px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <select class="item_lenght" name="size">
        <option value="Tyhjä">Valitse koko</option>
        <option data-price="47.00€" value="25cm"> 25cm x 150cm </option>
        <option data-price="48.00€" value="50cm"> 50cm x 150xm</option>
        <option data-price="49.00€" value="100cm"> 100cm x 150cm </option>
        </select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <select class="item_type" name="type">
        <option value="Ei valintaa">Valitse väri</option>
        <option data-name="Teipit (Harjattu Alumiini)" value="Harjattu Alumiini"> Harjattu Alumiini </option>
        <option data-name="Teipit (Musta hiilikuitu)" value="Musta hiilikuitu"> Musta hiilikuitu </option>
        <option data-name="Teipit (Valkoinen hiilikuitu)" value="Valkoinen hiilikuitu"> Valkoinen hiilikuitu </option>
        <option data-name="Teipit (Mattamusta)" value="Mattamusta"> Mattamusta </option>
        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Määrä:
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" value="1" class="item_Quantity" style="width:30px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hinta
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="item_price" value="0.00€">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>


        <a class="item_add" href="javascript:;"> Osta prkl </a>
```

What I'm possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to modify and get it's contents

```
$('.item_price').val($('option:selected', this).data('price'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `readonly="readonly"` for input istead of disabling it.

Also use `val()` for text field instead of `text()` for assigning value to `textfield`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/gjbKY/)**

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" class="item_price" value="0.00€">

$(".item_lenght").change(function() {
    $('.item_price').val($('option:selected', this).data('price'));
});​
```

Comment: Did that, but it still doesn't change the value.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use DOM Ready if your using jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// JQuery goes inside here
});
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving the value from and modifying input boxes, you must use the jQuery [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function rather than the `.text()` or `.html()` functions. Your jQuery should look like this:

```
$('.item_price').val($('option:selected', this).data('price'));
```

Comment: Yup, got that from an answer two minutes ago ;) Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen - But I added a sentence. =p Sorry to repeat, I just wanted to make it clear that the reason you must use val() is because it's an input element.

Comment: Yeah, I got that. And .html() when modifying paragraphs, spans and divs?

Comment: Use `.html()` whenever you are adding HTML content to the element. For example if you're adding a paragraph element, you would use `$("#id").html("<p>paragraph</p>")`. Use `.text()` whenever your adding simple text. If you add HTML content this way, it will simply be parsed as text. For example, if you use `$("#id").text("<p>paragraph</p")`, your element would contain the text "<p>paragraph</p>", rather than an HTML paragraph element.